# Best way to show number of results in a filter using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

First, a quick explanation of my current situation:

My webpage contains a list of (about 40, categorized) filters and a list of 400+ products.

I get the list of products using Ajax. By default 20 products are shown, but when you scroll to the bottom more products are added. Users can filter the results by clicking the desired option. It's like a simplified [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cell-Phones-Smartphones-/9355/i.html). Only difference is i don't reload the page when i click on a filter, but instead i use Ajax to get my products.

Now, ebay has these numbers next to every filter option, which shows the amount of results you'd get if you click that option. My question is, **What is the best way to show these numbers?**

My approach would be to run a sql query (`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sometable WHERE filter='something'`) for every filter option. However that means i have to run about 40 queries on load, and every time the user clicks an option (using Ajax). This seems like heavy server load, or am i wrong?

Comment: If you already are using Ajax I assume you use Json, why not make the filtering and counting in native javascript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter and then count the results using .length?

Comment: At the moment i call a PHP script using Ajax, which returns my products. On load 20 products are loaded (sql query: `LIMIT 0,20`). You suggest i load all products on load, put them in an array, and filter using javascript? ps. Yes i'm using json

Comment: Ah well if you want to count the available products in SQL you'll need to do as you suggested, bvery efficient way. Only way to be more efficient are by stored procedures.

Comment: Why not make one extra ajax call at page load just to get the total amount for each filter and keep that in a variable/object? then you can just make your other javascript calls to get your 20 products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with my first approach, but now i'm using `UNION` queries to get all counts. This way i only have to run 1 query instead of 1 query for every filter.